# PropertyInfo.GetValue() Throws: Object does not match target type

Tags: c#, .net, runtime-error, .net-6.0, system.reflection

I want to read all the values of each `row`

```cs
internal class ExcelTable<T> : IExcelTable where T : IExcelTableRow
{
    void Foo(){
        var props = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
        for (int r = 0; r < Rows.Count; r++)
        {
            IExcelTableRow row = Rows[r];
            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                // Throws error on the first prop = {Int32 Id}
                var v = p.GetValue(row); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it throws the following error

> System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target
> type.'

The type of `T` is `IExcelTableRow` and the implementation is `ExcelTranscationLogRow`.
It throws an error on the first row which has the following values

```cs
internal class ExcelTranscationLogRow : IExcelTableRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }                         // 3619     
    public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }// TransactionType.Execution
    public string Identifier { get; set; }              // "Placeholder"
    public TransactionStatus Status { get; set; }       // LogType.Success
    public LogType LogType { get; set; }                // TransactionStatus.Trace
    public string Log { get; set; }                     // "Getting KOT and CPR"
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }             // {05-07-2022 19:06:38}
}
```

It works fine for other implementations of `IExcelTableRow` e.g.

```cs
internal class ExcelTransactionRow : IExcelTableRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public TransactionStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you instantiating `ExcelTable<T>`? If each row can be of a different type, then you will need to move the assignment of `props` inside the row loop and assign for each row.

Untested example:

```
internal class ExcelTable : IExcelTable
{
    void Foo()
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < Rows.Count; r++)
        {
            IExcelTableRow row = Rows[r];
            var props = row.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                // Throws error on the first prop = {Int32 Id}
                var v = p.GetValue(row); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was a copy paste mistake. I forgot to change the type of `T` to the type which I was adding to the list of rows